# How do I pass a boolean for each post in my function view?

Tags: python, django

#### My `views.py`

```
def problems_list(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(created__range=['2020-03-01', '2020-03-31'])

    def is_liked(self):
        #if currently logged on user has already liked the post then
            is_liked = True
        #else
            is_liked = False


    context = {
        'posts': queryset,
        'is_liked': is_liked
    }
    return render(request, 'main/problem.html', context)
```

#### My `model.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True, default=None)
```

On each post I want to check wether the user has liked the post and if he has then pass a boolean variable tied to that post so that it shows he liked it. Im not sure how to add a variable that is tied to each post. I was reading some and saw that I might need a second model for my likes. Is this a better option?

I can run this in the shell for a single post but I want to be able to call it on all post.

```
In [1]: from main.models import Post

In [2]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [3]: user = User.objects.first()

In [4]: post = Post.objects.first()

In [5]: post.likes.all()
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<User: user1>, <User: user2>, <User: user3>]>

In [6]: post.likes.filter(username = user).exists()
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question. Does the code you have posted work?

Comment: If you want to log users who liked a specific post, then yes, a table e.g. with a foreign key to a) the post and b) the user would be the way to go

Comment: I just need to check whether the logged in user has liked the post.

Comment: Why not `liked_post = [ post.likes.filter(username=user).exists() for post in Post.objects.all()]` - but as per the docs if you need to perform 'table-level' operations on your models you should add a manager to your model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: If i used a for loop how would I call that to be rendered in a template?